# What is the best way to position <div> markers over a base image and allow for resize?

Tags: javascript, html, css, positioning

I have a underlay.jpg in a `<div id=underlay>` that I want to precisely place markers on. What is the best way to do this?

I'd like the image to fill the space of the div and markers to adjust when the window is resized. I'm assuming doing it in CSS would be the easiest but I'm not sure.

By the way, I'm generating the markers divs using Javascript. Here is my current code, which doesn't adjust correctly when I resize:

```
<div id="underlay">
  <img style="height:auto; width:auto; max-width:100%;" src="underlay.jpg">
   <div id="markers">
      <div id="marker1" style="left:36%; top:56%; position:absolute;">"1"</div>
      <div id="marker2" style="left:45%; top:76%; position:absolute;">"2"</div>
      <div id="marker3" style="left:24%; top:65%; position:absolute;">"3"</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly is wrong with that code?

Comment: The markers don't scale and line-up with the image when I resize the browser window.

Comment: That's strange, it works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/31480m7n/

Comment: Is your image (underlay.jpg) portrait or landscape (aspect ratio)?

Comment: @bjb568 your example doesn't work. You're missing `position: relative; display: inline-block;` on `#underlay`: http://jsfiddle.net/31480m7n/1/

Comment: It's a landscape image.

Comment: @SebastianHomeier Oh wat, I swear it worked before… Seems you're right tho.

Comment: @SebastianHomeier Thank you, this works! Is this the best way to do something like this? The alignment isn't perfect when the image gets really scaled down however. Is there a way to lay images precisely?

Comment: For example: http://jsfiddle.net/31480m7n/2/   Notice how the icons don't line-up with the eyes when you scale down.

Comment: Try this example: http://jsfiddle.net/31480m7n/9/

Comment: @SebastianHomeier - Yes! This is much better! Thank you!

Comment: Just posted the complete solution for you and others with similar problems :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a little step-by-step tutorial to achive this.

1. Shrink the container size ( `#underlay` ) to the image by using `display: inline-block`. Also add `position: relative`.
2. Set the markers container ( `.markers` ) to `position: absolute` and set the container dimensions by either using `height: 100%; width: 100%` or `top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;`.
3. Translate the marker contents to the center of the markers position: `transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);`.

```css
#underlay {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

#underlay>img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: auto;
}

#underlay>.markers {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#underlay>.markers>.marker {
  position: absolute;
}

#underlay>.markers>.marker>.marker-content {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="underlay">
  <img src="https://dailykitten.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/image17.jpg" />
  <div class="markers">
    <div id="marker1" class="marker" style="left:40%; top:50%;"><i class="marker-content fa fa-arrow-circle-down" style="color:white"></i></div>
    <div id="marker2" class="marker" style="left:60%; top:42%;"><i class="marker-content fa fa-arrow-circle-down" style="color:white"></i></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/31480m7n/14/

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the image as a `background-image` with CSS on `#underlay`, and take out the image tag:

```
#underlay {    
  background-image: url('underlay.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  height: 25em;
  width: 25em;
}
```

Play around with the background-size to get what works for you. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Comment: No, the image doesn't scale when I make it the background. The main problem with the original code I had was the aspect ratio of the image is set and scales to fit the window but the markers are based on the entire window. So when I shrink the window the markers don't line up with the base image.